# Libre Office "Create" is not enabled for Python Macro

Tags: python, macros, libreoffice-calc

Libreoffice 7.4.2.3 (x86) on Win7 Home (x64). That's the current version, but problem exists for any version. New (empty) spreadsheet. I'd like to create a new Python macro.

From Tools|Macros|Organise Macros|Basic, I get a dialog "Basic Macros" with a button labeled "New". The button is enabled.

From Tools|Macros|Organise Macros|Python, I get a dialog "Python Macros" with a button labeled "Create". That button is not enabled.

Why is it so? What do I have to do to enable Python macros in a Calc document?

Comment: Before asking, be sure to search to see if the question has been answered, as there are already several related questions on this site and around the web. If you have done this, mention the results of your search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'create' function for python macros in LibreOffice is *broken*.  It is *not implemented*. The disabled button is *not attached to anything*.  It has been that way for a long time, and there is no indication that it will ever by changed.

Answer (score 1):

Install [APSO](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/apso-alternative-script-organizer-for-python), then go to *Tools > Macros > Organize python scripts*. Under *My Macros*, go to *Menu > Create module*.

Either that, or go directly to your [LibreOffice User Directory](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/UserProfile) and use a text editor to create a .py file under Scripts/python.

Tutorial: http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html

See also: [Use a Python function as formula in LibreOffice Calc cells](https://superuser.com/questions/1297120/use-a-python-function-as-formula-in-libreoffice-calc-cells)